# $A=P^{-1}BP $ What is the name of this theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self-studying linear algebra and I watch some online courses to make things clearer  the professor gave this theorem: $A=P^{-1}BP ,\; $ *where* $A$ *and* $B$ *are  equivalent  and* $P$ *is an invertible matrix*, but said he didn't want to prove it. I wanted to look up the proof but didn't know the name of the theorem. If someone could tell me the name of the theorem that would be great.

Comment: What is your definition of ‘equivalent matrices’?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are *similar*, in the lingo, and this describes either a change of basis or an eigendecomposition or related ideas. Look up "Jordan Normal Form" or "Change of Basis Matrix" for more

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was the definition of equivalence. But I guess you could phrase it in terms of change of basis. I doubt it  has a name, but the proof is fairly direct.

Comment: @ Idiotic Shrike Thank you :D